# zsh array from variable does not work

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I using macos 10.14.2 (18C54) with zsh (latest version I couldn't find any versioning with zsh). If I create an array from a string it works. But If i use a variable containing the string split does not work. Is this expected behavior or something wrong with my environment? What is the correct way to do this if I am doing it wrong?

```
~ arr=(foo bar)
~ echo $arr[1]
foo
~ val='foo bar'
~ arr=($val)
~ echo $arr[1]
foo bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you wanted to do this in zsh, you would do the following.

```
~ arr=(foo bar)
~ echo $arr[1]
foo
~ val='foo bar'
~ eval "arr=($val)"
~ echo $arr[1]
foo
```

When you entered `arr=($val)`, zsh interpreted this to mean `arr=("foo bar")` even though you did not explicitly put a pair of `"` around `$val`. When I entered `eval "arr=($val)"`, zsh interpreted this to mean `arr=(foo bar)`. Using `eval` can be confusing. When in doubt, you can use the following experiment.

Say you want to know what `eval` sees and therefore what really will be executed. Start with the statement shown below. Here, I assume you have already entered `val='foo bar'`.

```
eval "arr=($val)"
```

Now replace `eval` with `echo` as shown below.

```
echo "arr=($val)"
```

Entering the above command produces the following result.

```
arr=(foo bar)
```

This what zsh will actually be executing.

Comment: thank you it worked. also thank you for the tip. I will use it.